# mysqld: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /root/.my.cnf at line 1!

Tags: docker, mysql

I'm trying to create a `.my.cnf` file for my MySQL docker-container that would allow me to prefill the user and password for the MySQL client. To achieve this I created the following dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:5.7
RUN touch ~/.my.cnf && echo -e "[client]\nuser=root\npassword=$(echo $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD)" >> ~/.my.cnf
```

But when starting the container I always get the errors:

```
mysql5.7-database    | 2021-04-01 18:38:51+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.33-1debian10 started.
mysql5.7-database    | 2021-04-01 18:38:51+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: mysqld failed while attempting to check config
mysql5.7-database    |  command was: mysqld --verbose --help --log-bin-index=/tmp/tmp.5imGsNRXXC
mysql5.7-database    |  mysqld: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /root/.my.cnf at line 1!
mysql5.7-database    | mysqld: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
```

- The environment variable `$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` is successfully set with the correct password.
- I can login with the password in the `$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`

The result of `echo -e "[client]\nuser=root\npassword=$(echo $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD)"` is:

```
[client]
user=root
password=<my-generated-password>
```

When I create the `.my.cnf` file manually in the running docker container, it works like a charm. Any advise?

Answer (score 1):

The default Dockerfile shell is `sh`. I don't think echo there has the `-e` modifier for backslash. Newline & other special symbols will work by default. In your command, resulting `.my.cnf` would contain a litteral `-e`.

Remove `-e` **or** use the original command in Dockerfile in a different shell, for instance:

```
RUN /bin/bash -c '<your-command>'
```